# Hisense Touch cannot open file picker/login menus (black screens and crashes)

Tags: applications, crashes

I have a Hisense Touch with Android 11 and Touch OS 1, it has Google Play Services from a seller on Aliexpress. I cannot open the file picker in installed applications even though all permissions are allowed, etc. The crash also occurs when clicking the login button on Pocket and the share button in the file manager. When the apps I'm trying to use crash, there is no dialogue box.

I'm new to Android but from what I understand, this is a device marketed to the Chinese market and has some Chinese ROM of Android with workarounds installed by the seller, this is an e-reader device.

[My post on XDA](https://xdaforums.com/t/hisense-touch-cannot-open-file-picker-opens-to-black-screen-then-crashes.4652606/) has a recording of the crash occurring and a log file that adb spit out that I'm not too sure what to do with, but KiwiBrowser is the main app I am trying to use that keeps crashing. Thank you!

Comment: I dont think we can do much if the app itself is crashing, because its badly written.  I would avoid cheap technical stuff from these outlets.  I bought some luggage tiles and the instructions were directing me to iPhone app instead of Android.  They didnt respond for weeks, eventually I got my money back.  Once I had send teh tiles back, they came back with the correct site for Android.